# How to get date and time of captured image?

Tags: matlab

Using MATLAB I am capturing an image from a webcam. I want to extract the date and time of the captured image. How can I do that?

This is my code::

```
vid = videoinput('winvideo', 1, 'RGB24_640x480');
for i=1:10
    img=getsnapshot(vid);
    fname=['image' num2str(i)];
    imwrite(img,fname,'jpg');
    pause(3);
end
```

Comment: why not just get time right before you capture the image?

Comment: look into the [`clock` function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clock.html?refresh=true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A webcam probably doesn't have the built-in clock, therefore you won't be able to extract the date-time information from the captured image.

Instead, use one of the built-in Matlab functions, e.g.

```
datestr(now, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss.fff')
```

will return the current timestamp in the ISO 8601-like format.

The functions you may want to use:

- [now](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html)
- [clock](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html)
- [datetime](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html)

Comment: Does that "datestr" function stores the date and time with the captured image?

Comment: @Pram_Haunter, no, it only formats it the way you want. There is no built-in Matlab function to save metadata (EXIF) in JPEG files. However you can do it using [exiftool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExifTool) as mentioned in [another thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9058583/674976).